# how to retained user session logged in between tabs?

Tags: angular, web-applications, browser-security

In an Angular application I am trying to retain user's `logged_in` property until he manually logs out using `localStorage`. Though the data is encrypted and saved in `localStorage`, we can manually copy the data and paste it in after a user logs out, then security is broken here (we will be able to access the application without logging in just with the encrypted key). How can we achieve this functionality? It is okay if a user gets logged out if he closes all tabs. Instead of using `localStorage`/`SessionStorage`/`Cookie`, how can we achieve this? What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this would be to have JWT stored in localstorage. Thereby, upon starting the application(By visiting the url) trigger a service method to send the JWT token to the backend and validate it. If the validation is successful, proceed with normal flow else clear the localstorage and navigate to login page.

The best place to do this would be at the ngOnInit of the app.component. Moreover the JWT can have expiration time, hence after a stipulated time (Preferably an hour which can be configured), the token becomes invalid. This can be done to avoid any other user to use the same credential.
In app.component.ts

```
   ...
    export class AppComponent implements onInit{
        constructor(private authService: AuthService){
        }   
        ngOnInit(){
            this.authService.authenticate()
        }
    }
```

In AuthService

```
...
export class AuthService{
    token: string;  

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,private router: Router){
    }

    authenticate(){
        this.token = localStorage.get("JWT");
        this.http.post<any>("YOUR_BACKEND",{token: this.token})
        .subscribe((data)=>{
            //do nothing        
        },
        (err)=>{
            this.router.navigate(["/login"]);   
            localstorage.removeItem("JWT")
        })          
    }   

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but if we know the jwt token we can then use the same token and login in another system rite?

Comment: Within the expiration time, that is possible. But JWT is a long encrypted string hence there is problem only if someone copies the token. This is the general downside of using client side storage.

Comment: but using local storage is creating security vulnerability.. so i cant do this approach..how else this can be achieved.. also we have only one user and no database.. with no session time out.. which user will be logged in until he manually logs out

Answer (score 0):

Since using cookie seems to be moderate vulnerability, i used cookies with encoded data.